# Wrap Text in a Circle Shape Using HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to wrap the text in a circle shape, I have done everything but the text is messed up with the info icon. What I need is to start the text slightly bottom to the circle so that the text will be responsive.

I have attached the screenshot as well as the Tailwind Play link.

> Here is the Output:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/bOKYfNPjxF

> It should be look like this:
> [image]

```
<style>
   .svg {
   fill: currentColor;
   height: auto;
   max-width: 66vmin;
   transform-origin: center;
   width: 135px;
   }
</style>
<div class="text-black">
   <fieldset>
      <div class="bg-gray-200 p-4 mt-2 items-center flex grid grid-cols-5 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-5 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8"  style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.08);">
         <!--new -->
         <div class="relative  h-full flex justify-center items-center">
            <label data-id="Rosehip Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
               <svg class="svg absolute" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
                  <defs>
                     <path id="circle"
                        d="
                        M 50, 50
                        m -37, 0
                        a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                        a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                  </defs>
                  <text font-size="10">
                     <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                     </textPath>
                  </text>
               </svg>
               <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full">
               <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Marula-Oil.png" class="rounded-full" alt="">
               </span>
               <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Argan Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Argan Oil_10" class="sr-only">
               <div class="oil_label_checked_icon absolute inset-x-0 top-0 transform translate-y-px hidden">
                  <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-1/2">
                     <svg class=" h-6 w-6 text-green-600 ml-10 mt-20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </label>
            <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute bottom-0" data-id="Rosehip Oil">
               <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-6">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-white mt-2" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                     <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- <span class="absolute inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded-full text-xs font-medium bg-black text-white mb-2 hidden"> $10 </span> -->
            <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-white bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex justify-center mt-5 mb-5 remove_preview_oil_btn hidden">
         <span class="">
         <button type="button" class=" border border-red-600 rounded-md shadow-sm py-2 px-4 inline-flex justify-center text-sm font-medium text-white bg-red-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500">Remove from cart</button>
         </span>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;"` to your SVG text seems to work:

```css
.svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 66vmin;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 135px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="text-black">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="bg-gray-200 p-4 mt-2 items-center flex grid grid-cols-5 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-5 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-x-8" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.08);">
      <!--new -->
      <div class="relative  h-full flex justify-center items-center">
        <label data-id="Rosehip Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
               <svg class="svg absolute" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
                  <defs>
                     <path id="circle"
                        d="
                        M 50, 50
                        m -37, 0
                        a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                        a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                  </defs>
                  <text font-size="10" style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                     <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                     </textPath>
                  </text>
               </svg>
               <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full">
               <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Marula-Oil.png" class="rounded-full" alt="">
               </span>
               <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Argan Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Argan Oil_10" class="sr-only">
               <div class="oil_label_checked_icon absolute inset-x-0 top-0 transform translate-y-px hidden">
                  <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-1/2">
                     <svg class=" h-6 w-6 text-green-600 ml-10 mt-20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </label>
        <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute bottom-0" data-id="Rosehip Oil">
          <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-6">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-white mt-2" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                     <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                  </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <span class="absolute inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded-full text-xs font-medium bg-black text-white mb-2 hidden"> $10 </span> -->
        <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-white bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center mt-5 mb-5 remove_preview_oil_btn hidden">
      <span class="">
         <button type="button" class=" border border-red-600 rounded-md shadow-sm py-2 px-4 inline-flex justify-center text-sm font-medium text-white bg-red-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-red-500">Remove from cart</button>
         </span>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```